# Set a Role Condition to invoke a Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-iam

I want to enable a service account to invoke a Cloud Run service and restrict the invocation to a specific URL (eg.: https://myservice/specific).

Most of GCP resources allow for conditional restrictions using IAM Conditions (like picture below).

I'm wondering if Cloud Run does support IAM Conditions, and I case it does not what's the recommended way to achieve such kind of restriction.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Do you want to autoriser a service account to access one and only one CLoud Run services (and not all of the services deployed on a project)? Or do you want to restrict the access to a specific PATH on your Cloud Run service? (like a service account authorized to access to an admin path)

Comment: Yes I would like to restrict specific HTTP methods, or paths...

Answer (score 1):

IAM service is a free Google Cloud product that manage IAM access for Google Cloud product.

That being said, go back to your case: You have a service account that you want to restrict (or allow) the access to Cloud Run product. No problem, you can grant the run.invoker role to access to Cloud Run.

If you want finer/inner Cloud Run service permission, you should guess that it is not possible with IAM service. Indeed, the inner permission (or business permission) are specific to your code, and not to the Google Cloud code (i.e. the Google Cloud products).

And IAM Conditions won't help you in that case. IAM Conditions applies on Google Cloud product definition. For instance, you can grant a service account to access to Cloud Run services with the service name starting by `something`. But again, it's only on Google Cloud product information.

IAM can't help you on that. You could have a look at [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway). Or, you should have to implement the checks directly in the /path code to filter the authorized calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Honestly I don't full agree with sentence "inner permission ... are specific to your code, and not to the Google Cloud code", since writing permission logic into the code makes permissions not manageable from outside the app. I see some GCP products supporting conditions for fine/inner permissions, and I'm used to some IDPs allowing to set permissions down to a single resource level (sub path, HTTP method, etc).

BTW, probably adding an extra layer with API Gateway would work. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#set-up-sa), you can grant your Service Account a "`Cloud Run Invoker`" role.

You can read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) for more information.

I've tried to add the role "`Cloud Run Invoker`" to a user and it works. Just try it to a service account.

Comment: I know how to use the cloud run invoker role... my question is about something else

Answer (score 0):

The service accountIAM permission,you can achieve this while deploying/editing a service you have the option to select "Allow only authenticated requests". This would basically do two things, one is restrict access to users listed within the IAM permissions list of the project. Secondly, you'd be able to give invocation permissions to email addresses and/or email domains [Documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access#adding_users).As also can be inferred from the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service), frontend can securely and privately invoke backend by leveraging the Invoker IAM role:
Grant the service account of frontend the Cloud Run Invoker IAM role.
When you issue request from frontend to backend, you must attach an identity token to the request, see [here for code examples](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#nodejs)

While there are other options to [authenticate to Cloud Run services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview) whose "Require authentication" option is turned on, all of the options issue and use a Google-issued token one way or another. That's because the option "Require authentication" uses [IAM to secure Cloud Run services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access)

Comment: my question is about something else